# Show post count in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, counter

Is it possible to get the exact counter of each post for display in a theme I'm making? So for example if I have 100 posts, the last post will have a number of 100, the one before that: 99, and so on. I can't use the post's ID on this since this is always incremented by 2 (most of the time) making it highly inappropriate as a counter.

Comment: post Id won't increase by 2, it will increase with each revision you make. when ever you make a post/page(or any kind of posttype) of upload anything, and even menu items. These all go in the wp_posts tabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, look at the results you will get the idea.
Don't forget the array starts with 0 not 1.

Each array item will contain the post ID. so if Item(key) nr 15 is the same as the current page ID, then the current item is #16(15+1)

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT `ID`
    FROM `$wpdb->posts`
    WHERE `post_status` = 'publish'
    AND `post_type` = 'post'
    ORDER BY `post_date` ASC
    "
;
$count = $wpdb->get_col($query);

var_dump($count);
```

moar info: [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column)
Do look at the query if you agree with my order.

Comment: This worked perfectly with a small modification to your query. I used this instead: `SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type IN ('post', 'gallery', 'portfolio') AND post_status='publish' AND id=$id ORDER BY post_date ASC`. Now I can generate numbers as a whole for all types of posts.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a "counter" there, something like this:

```
$i=1;

while(have_posts):

  ....
  <h2><?php echo $i.' - ';?><?php the_title();?>
  ...
  $i++;

endwhile;
```